# Objective C: UITableView hide animation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on a prototype (I'm way too green on Objective C) which has a button that hides or shows a tableview. The tableview appears from bottom to top, and when you press that button it will hide that tableview by sliding it back to bottom. That tableview is a subview btw.

Here's the thing, the "show" animation works great but the hide animation doesn't, it actually slides the tableview into view from the top so there's clearly something I'm not getting right. Here's the code:

```
if(self.showLists){
    self.showLists = NO;

    //This is the show animation which is working properly

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 0-self.tableView.frame.size.height)];


    [UIView commitAnimations];

}else{

    self.showLists = YES;

    //This is the hide animation, the one that's not working as intended

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.frame.size.height, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 0)];


    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

I'm sure it's totally silly but sometimes the smallest details are the worst. As far as I understand, CGRectMake's second argument is the y location where I want the tableview to be when the animation is completed, 0 for top, and the tableview's height (say 500) for bottom right?

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you using auto layout for setting up the tableview?

Comment: Yes I am, you think it's creating a conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are set up a view with auto layout you should not change it's frame. You should animate it's constraints. In this case you could animate it's centerX and centerY constraint if it is set. Also it's easier to use the UIView animateWithDuration method.

Animate to the middle, assuming centerX and centerY are the horizontal and vertical center NSLayoutConstraint of the tableview.

```
centerX.constant = 0;
centerY.constant = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
           [self.view layoutIfNeeded];    
           } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Great answer! But I have one more question, if I use this modifying the top constraint and setting the tableview's height, say topConstraint.constant = 600; the resulting effect is that the tableview is no longer visible but no animation is performed, I played with the duration but even if I set it for a second the effect is the same, perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Sry the problem was in my code, you should change the constant outside of the animation block, and call layout if needed on the view inside the animation block. I've updated my answer,

Comment: Awesome, works great now and thank you for the Autolayout observation, that is something that there was no way I would have figure out by myself in the near future!

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler approach would be to use transform to modify the `tableView` layer. When using a transform, we don't have to update the frame, we simply just set the new position (translation)!

```
CGFloat tableViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.frame);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                 animations:^{
                     // set the transform to animate to
                     self.tableView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, tableViewHeight, 0);
               } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // when animation is finished, reset the transform
                     // if you also want to hide the tableView, here 
                     // would be a good way to put it
                     self.tableView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
               }];
```

Comment: Excellent answer too! I wish I could accept more than one answer, but I thought that the Autolayout issue was important. Your answer is great too, all I had to do next was change the tableview's alpha value on completion in order to remain hidden as you pointed out, otherwise it would popup back to it's origin but the animation was what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try this line in your code

```
self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

Hope it helps.